# Get duration in years and months

Tags: c#, date

I have period of 2 dates: **`2011-07-05`** and **`2013-10-05`**

How can I get duration in format: **`2 years 3 months`**. What is the best approach?
Can I create any extension method or a new class for that? Please suggest? Any help will be appreciated

I have done so far:

```
 public static string GetDuration(DateTime date1, DateTime date2) {
    int oldMonth = date2.Month;
    while (oldMonth == date2.Month) {
        date1 = date1.AddDays(-1);
        date2 = date2.AddDays(-1);
    }

    int years = 0, months = 0;

    // getting number of years
    while (date2.CompareTo(date1) >= 0) {
        years++;
        date2 = date2.AddYears(-1);
    }
    date2 = date2.AddYears(1);
    years--;

    // getting number of months and days
    oldMonth = date2.Month;
    while (date2.CompareTo(date1) >= 0) {
        date2 = date2.AddDays(-1);
        if ((date2.CompareTo(date1) >= 0) && (oldMonth != date2.Month)) {
            months++;
            oldMonth = date2.Month;
        }
    }

    return 
        "Difference: " +
        years.ToString() + " years" +
        ", " + months.ToString() + " months";
}
```

Comment: `var duration = (Date1 - Date2).ToString("yyyy MM")`

Comment: Thanks but there is an error on `ToString()`

Comment: No overload for method 'ToString' takes 1 arguments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static string GetDuration(DateTime date1, DateTime date2) 
{
    TimeSpan difference = date2 - date1;
    DateTime result = DateTime.MinValue.AddDays(difference.TotalDays);

    int years = result.Year - 1;
    int months = result.Month - 1;
    int days = result.Day - 1;

    return $"{years} years {months} months";
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for help

Answer (score 0):

```
public static string GetDuration(DateTime date1, DateTime date2) 
{       
    var period = date2.AddDays(1) - date1;
    var date = new DateTime(period.Ticks);
    var totalYears = date.Year - 1;
    var totalMonths = ((date.Year - 1) * 12) + date.Month - 1;
    var extraMonths = totalMonths - (totalYears * 12);

    return string.Format("{0} years {1} months", totalYears, extraMonths);
}
```

You can see in action [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/e2UMW1).

Answer (score 0):

without thinking too much about the actual dates, here's a quick solution

```
int year, month;

if(date2.Month >= date1.Month)
{
  years = date2.Year - date1.Year;
  months = date2.Month - date1.Month;
}
else
{
  years = date2.Year - date1.Year - 1;
  months= date2.Month + 12 - date1.Month;
}
```